InvalidOperationException: There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'PricingID'
I'm trying to post car reservation and although all values posting when I debugged but still get error.
I also checked network in developer tools and all values seen in payload. But I get an error about PricingID like

There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key 'PricingID'

public async Task<IActionResult> Index(int id)
{
    ViewBag.v1 = "Rent A Car";
    ViewBag.v2 = "Rent A Car Form";
    ViewBag.v3 = id;

    var client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
    var responseMessage = await client.GetAsync("https://localhost:44380/api/Location");

    var jsonData = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ResultLocationDto>>(jsonData);

    List<SelectListItem> values2 = (from x in values
                                    select new SelectListItem
                                           {
                                               Text = x.Name,
                                               Value = x.Id.ToString()
                                           }).ToList();
    ViewBag.v = values2;

    var responseMessage2 = await client.GetAsync("https://localhost:44380/api/Pricing");
    var jsonData2 = await responseMessage2.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var pricings = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ResultPricingDto>>(jsonData2);

    List<SelectListItem> values3 = (from x in pricings
                                    select new SelectListItem
                                           {
                                               Text = x.Name,
                                               Value = x.Id.ToString()
                                           }).ToList();
    ViewBag.pricing = values3;

    return View();
}

View:
@model CreateReservationDto
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/UILayout/Index.cshtml";
}

<div class="col-md-12 block-9 mb-md-5"> 
    <form class="bg-light p-5 contact-form" method="post">
        <h3 class="alert alert-success">Car Reservation Form</h3>
        <br />
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="CarID" value="@ViewBag.v3" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Car">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" asp-for="Name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" asp-for="Surname" class="form-control" placeholder="Surname">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" asp-for="Email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" asp-for="Phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.PricingID, (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.pricing, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.PickUpLocationID, (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.v, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(x=>x.DropOffLocationID,(List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.v,new{@class="form-control"})
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" asp-for="Age" class="form-control" placeholder="Age">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" asp-for="DriverLicenseYear" class="form-control" placeholder="Driver License Year">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <textarea  asp-for="Description" id="" cols="30" rows="7" class="form-control" placeholder="Your requests"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Send Reservation" class="btn btn-primary py-3 px-5">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

I can post it by swagger correctly.

According to the error message ,it seems the values3 is null which caused the issue, have you check the result of the  List<SelectListItem> values3 = (from x in pricings                                     select new SelectListItem                                            {                                                Text = x.Name,                                                Value = x.Id.ToString()                                            }).ToList(); is null or not?

@BrandoZhang it's not null. It shows in ui as dropdownlist and when I send data then I see the value of PricingID interestingly.

When you face this error during the firstly loading for this page?

@BrandoZhang No. After posting.

@BrandoZhang Now I realized that when I change the order of dropdownlist of pricingID with PickUpLocationID in view part, then get the same error for pickuplocationID interestingly.

What's the post method and the view load method?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Problem solved!
I had a status property in CreateReservationDto and I fill it as default normally so I forgot to remove this property in dto.
